# Can someone explain me how to do a JSONP call like I'm five?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I already have a .json object in a server. It is correct and has no syntax errors (valid json). I want to call this object through JSONP because it resides in a server different from my app's.

I think I understand how to achieve it client-wise, but I have no idea what to do in relation to the server part. I am having errors all the time when following the info already on the web. Any help?

Comment: What language (PHP, ruby, java, c#, …)?

Comment: javascript/jquery, sorry

Comment: do you mean the server's script i'm using? in that case, PHP

Comment: Your mommy and daddy give you $10 to open up a lemonade stand.... wait....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JSONP is basically a "hack" to allow sites to load data and ignore the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  It works by appending a `<script>` tag to your page.

The *de facto* way is to send a callback in your request.  The server would then take that name and generate a JS file that calls that function with the data.

Using jQuery, you can make a JSONP call by simply appending `?callback=?` to your URL when doing `$.getJSON`.

Example:

```
$.getJSON('http://YourSite.com/path/to/json.php?callback=?', function(data){
    console.log(data); // this will be parsed for you
});
```

Or, you can use the full `$.ajax` method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://YourSite.com/path/to/json.php',
    dataType: 'jsonp', // this tells jQuery to add "callback=?" for you
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // this will be parsed for you
    }
});
```

Instead of makning an AJAX call, jQuery will actually append:

```
<script src="http://YourSite.com/path/to/json.php?callback=jQuery12345"></script>
```

to your page (note: `jQuery12345` will be randomly generated).

Then on your server, you need to respond with a valid JavaScript file.  It should contain a call to the `callback` function passed in the query string.  Something like this:

```
jQuery12345({your: ['json', 'data']});
```

An example in PHP (adapt to whatever server-side language you use) could be:

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2,'c' => 3];
$callback = $_GET['callback'];

header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo "{$callback}(".json_encode($array).");";
```

That's all there is to it.  See the Wikipedia page on JSONP for more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: The PHP part was what I needed to read. I will try it and I hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome :-D

Answer (score 6):

JSONP has nothing to do with JSON. Here's a simple (but useless) example:

- **The client** makes a script element: `<script src="http://example.com/foo.js>`. This causes the browser to fetch `foo.js` from `example.com`.
- **The server** hears the request for `foo.js`. The server serves the contents of `foo.js` to the client (suppose it's just `alert(1)`).
- **The client** gets the contents of `foo.js` and runs those contents as a script. (So, the client does `alert(1)`.)

**How is this useful?** Well, you can pass *arguments* with your request to foo.js:

- **The client** does `<script src="http://example.com/foo.js?arg=123>`
- **The server** hears a request for `foo.js?arg=123`. The server does something with that `arg` value -- let's suppose it multiplies it by 2 (but it could do something useful, like look up the username for the user with uid `123`). The server then sends back the script content `alert(246)`.
- **The client runs the script from the server and alerts `246`.

**Okay, this is great if I want the client to `alert` stuff, but how can I do something useful?** There's just one last leap we have to make: provide the *name of a client function* as an argument:

- **The client** defines a function `myFunc` as: `function myFunc(a) { alert(a) }`
- **The client** does `<script src="http://example.com/foo.js?callback=myFunc&arg=123>`
- **The server** hears the request for `foo.js?callback=myFunc&arg=123`, and its server-side scripting knows it should use the `callback` argument as the name of the function called in `foo.js`. The server sends back the script content `myFunc(246)`.
- **The client** runs `myFunc(246)`. Here, we've specified `myFunc` to just alert its argument, but you could have it do anything you like.

**That's how JSONP works.** The client provides arguments to the server in a script URL, including the name of a client-side function, and the server sends back **a script** (*not* JSON!) for the client to run. Of course, the resulting script can contain JSON in it, like `myFunc({ 'foo' : 5 })`, but ultimately, that JSON is just part of the script content.

Comment: Good basic description.  I like how you noted that you can return any value in the callback, not just an object. :-)